# Albums and images from Photo Gallery with Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model

I have a photo gallery library. I want to get all albums and their images.
Now I get all albums (root level items) with something like this:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(_url);
_mylib = web.Lists.GetByTitle("mylib");
_albums = _list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
```

_albums represents albums, on the root of the gallery. How do I get files/items in each of these albums?

```
mylib
-album1
--image1.jpg
--image2.jpg
-album2
--image1.jpg
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar to this recently (Picture Libraries, Client object model, silverlight).

What I did different was each "album" was in it's own Picture Library.

When I give the user the option to select an album, I gather a ListCollection of lists where the BaseType is that of a Picture Library (can't remember the exact number now, search around for it though) - and put this list into a DropdownList.

Stick an event handler onto the DropdownList such that when it's changed, the selected item is pulled out, put into a CAML Query which loads all items from a specified list (by GUID).

In short? Avoid folders, use separate lists/libraries instead. If you must keep them in the same library, then add a column to store an "Album Name". Then do a CAML Query to filter based on a value in this column, this will return all files in a specific "album".

Comment: I managed to get all albums + images using Folder and Folder.Files in them. The only problem now is that I must test it at work. I will accept you answer if no better comes, because it's one of the solutions to the problem.